# Checking if two strings? are identical and returning true if they are

Tags: java, string, if-statement, methods

I have a question regarding comparing two strings? and checking if they are identical. Below is the question explenation

```
// returns true if f.makeMolecular() is is equal to this.makeMolecular 
    // e.g. terms = {Term('B',3),Term('A',6)} and f = {Term('B',1),Term('A',3),Term('B',1),Term('A',3)} 
    // would return true 
    // The makeMolecular() method sorts the Term Strings into Alphabetical order with the number linked to the letter added and following behind the letter.
```

E.G  Both of the makeMolecular should return a string of "A6B3"

I want to check if  they are identical using and IF statement and taking advatange of the == method in Java.

Below folows one solution to checking if the strings are identical, but as mentioned i would like to do it with an iff statement.

```
  {

  this.makeMolecular();
    f.makeMolecular();
    return identical(f);



}
```

This is what i have tried so far:

```
char b = f.makeMolecular();  
char b = f.makeMolecular();

  if (a==b){
      return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
```

and i get the following error: Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to char. I am quite certain the use of "char" is incorrect here, but i am not sure of what to use instead.

So I am wondering how to convert these strings(?) to a constant and then checking if  they are identical via an IF-statement.

// Edit:

By request; this is the method for  makeMolecular()

```
public void makeMolecular()
{ 
    char element = ' ';
    int atoms = 0;
    ArrayList<Term> mol = new ArrayList<Term>();

    while (terms.size() > 0){
        if (mol.size() > 0 && mol.get(mol.size() - 1).getElement() == nextElement().getElement()  ){
            atoms = mol.get(mol.size() - 1).getAtoms() + nextElement().getAtoms();
            element = nextElement().getElement();
            mol.remove(mol.size() - 1);
            mol.add(new Term(element,atoms));
        }
        else {
            mol.add(nextElement());
        }
        terms.remove(nextElement());
    }

    terms = mol;
}
```

Comment: Updated with the method for makeMolecular()     to cleare things up.

Comment: `makeMolecular` is a void function. It can't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
 String a = f.makeMolecular();
 String b = f.makeMolecular();

 if(a.equals(b))
     return true;
 else
     return false;
```

Comment: It should be `return a.equals(b);`. Or `Objects.equals(a, b)` if `a` might be null.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but  when i try this solution i get the following error: "Incompatible types: void cannot be converted to java.lang.String

Comment: What is return type of makeMolecular() method?

Comment: @Amriteya `void`, clearly.

Comment: I am not sure, but it is from public void makeMolecular()  who then turns it into an ArrayList i think ? Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: @Andy He hasn't given the code for the method makeMolecular(). Couldn't be sure about that

Comment: the code of the method makeMolecular() is as follow:                                        public void makeMolecular()
    { 
        char element = ' ';
        int atoms = 0;
        ArrayList<Term> molecule = new ArrayList<Term>();

Comment: while (terms.size() > 0){
            if (molecule.size() > 0 && molecule.get(molecule.size() - 1).getElement() == nextElement().getElement()  ){
                
                
                
                atoms = molecule.get(molecule.size() - 1).getAtoms() + nextElement().getAtoms();
                element = nextElement().getElement();
                molecule.add(new Term(element,atoms));
                molecule.remove(molecule.size() - 1);
           }
         else {
                molecule.add(nextElement());
   }
   terms.remove(nextElement());
  }
        
 terms = molecule;

Comment: Yes, clearly: "**void** cannot be converted to java.lang.String". And no, @HankyPanky, that `a` is undefined is not the reason, since it is defined in this code. Redefining `b` would give a different error first.

Comment: I can make an edit to the original questions to include the method makeMolecular() if that clears things up.